# How to remove a number from the end of an URL using .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I got plenty of URLS that end with -xxx, where xxx is a number between 000 and 999.
For example:

```
http://a.com/imagea-000
http://a.com/category1/imageb-002
http://a.com/category1/category2/imagec-999
```

How must a RewriteCond/RewriteRule be specified in .httaccess to remove the number, including the '-' from the end of the url? So the final URLS look like:

```
http://a.com/imagea
http://a.com/category1/imageb
http://a.com/category1/category2/imagec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

- `-\d+/?$` will match hyphen followed by 1 or digits and an optional slash at end of URI.
- `(.+?)` will match anything before above pattern and capture it as group #1
- Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.